# How should we treat questions involving mobile computers like barcode scanners that use Windows Mobile?

Tags: support, allowed-topics, policy, on-topic

**UPDATE** - I found [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone?referrer=bw_WFK5tJdAgCqb_Ka-8vA2) over on area51.
It suggests a StackExchange site for Windows Mobile.  Go follow it if you want to see this!

---

I've been using a computer like this at work for the last few months.

[image: Dolphin 9550]

This stand alone computer is complete system that has the ability to access the internet via IE over WiFi, edit documents via Word, and so forth.

It doesn't have the ability to make phone calls, send SMS messages, or any other phone-related things unless a VoIP softphone program were to be installed (like Skype on a desktop).

I could be wrong, but to me this machine counts as a "computer" according to the SU FAQ.

Are questions about mobile computers like this on topic?  I couldn't find another SE site that was tailored to such machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it runs Windows **Mobile** then I'd treat it just as any other mobile OS and close it as off-topic. Technically there's no difference between that device and an iPod Touch.

I understand that its not fun that we don't allow these questions, but its a slippery slope of allowing such questions. I can run Ubuntu on a N900, but that doesn't mean you should ask questions about that either.

Furthermore, you might have a hard time finding someone who can answer it, for the simple reason that this would be the *only* Windows Mobile focused question on the site.

So I think I would have to disappoint you and say that there's currently no SE site for these questions.

Comment: Agreed. Then we'd also have to allow iPad questions because you can also use Internet/WiFi and you can edit documents. And then maybe Android tablets as well? And then this, then that, *blah* *blah* :) (Also, it falls under the definition of an *electronic device*, which would be off topic anyway)

Comment: Is there a Windows Mobile SE?

Comment: There used to be a Gadgets.SE, but it was closed because there's too many different gadgets and not enough users who can answer questions about them. So no, there's no site for you atm

Comment: "Technically there's no difference between that device and an iPod Touch".. So.. Tempting... Must.. Resist... Obvious.. Trolling.. Attempt... ;)