# How should we handle questions involving (non-Windows CE-based) Windows Embedded?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Similar to [How should we treat questions involving mobile computers like barcode scanners that use Windows Mobile?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2870/how-should-we-treat-questions-involving-mobile-computers-like-barcode-scanners-t), how should we handle questions involving Windows Embedded 7 or other non-Windows CE-based [Windows Embedded](http://www.windows.com/embedded) operating systems? These operating systems tend to be more similar to desktop Windows than Windows Mobile but are used on embedded systems.  Are these questions on topic, or should they be closed?

Example: [Reconfigure a Windows Embedded 7 device to allow changes to be saved](https://superuser.com/questions/513613/reconfigure-a-windows-embedded-7-device-to-allow-changes-to-be-saved)

Comment: I think Windows Embedded is _very_ superuser-y. From my point of view it should be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd want to say that these questions are on topic as long as they involve hardware that is reasonably similar to typical consumer PC hardware or is applicable to consumer PC hardware or software.

For example, a question related to a kiosk or other PC-like embedded system running [Windows Embedded Standard 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-compact-7.aspx) would be on topic, but a question involving POS-specific features on a device running [Windows Embedded POSReady 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-pos-ready.aspx) would be off topic.  Questions on PC-like hardware running [Windows Embedded Enterprise](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-enterprise.aspx) may also be on topic.  Borderline cases, such as those involving software functionality found on PCs but on an embedded device not similar to a PC, should be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Of course, questions on devices running [Windows Embedded Compact 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-compact-7.aspx) and [Windows Embedded Automotive 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-automotive-7.aspx) are off topic, as they are not similar to consumer PC hardware.